# CSS :before superscript "6"?

Tags: css, unicode, pseudo-element, css-content

Is there a way to add a superscript "6" into the "content" CSS property for a pseudo element? I've been all over the web, trying different Unicode strings and glyph codes to try to get this to work, but haven't found a solution.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Sorry for not clarifying... I'm needing to put the superscript "6" amongst other text in the same "content" property. Looks like I'll need to just define a different encoding for my CSS and drop it in as a literal character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The obvious way does work, in fact](http://jsfiddle.net/PjrdL/):

```
span:before {
    content: "⁶";
}
```

You may have to be careful with encodings used and specified in this case, though.

As BoltClock mentions, you can also escape the character as `\2076` if encoding problems are a concern (e.g. if your server forces legacy codepages and you cannot change that).

Comment: That looks like what the user was originally after, but would you agree that the CSS method of changing font-size/v-align is superior?

Comment: Ultimately I'm looking for the ability to add this in the "content" property amongst other text, i.e. "content: 'This is 10⁶'".

Comment: @Gray - It depends. If the user needs additional text that is not in super-script, this is the only option.

Comment: The code point for this character is U+2076; to express it as an escape sequence you would therefore use `\2076`. Of course, if your document is UTF-8 encoded you can just use the character directly.

Comment: I feel more comfortable using your "\2076" suggestion. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, @BoltClock.

Comment: How was that superscript 6 done? I can copy it but don't know how to recreate.  Can any char be done this way? Can a #?

Comment: @AndreBulatov: Character Map, copy from there. And yes, any character can be copied from somewhere you can copy it from.

Comment: @Joey -- Thank you.  I was hoping you were gonna say you created it somehow in Word or something (which doesn't work for me; pastes regular char).  When I use OSx character viewer, I can't find the 6 you used, nor the superscript hash I'm looking for badly to use in CSS pseudo content.  Any idea where I might find one of those?  This doesn't feel right, and if I find it, I'll copy/paste it everywhere and never let it go.

Comment: @Andre: Never used OS X, but it should be in the Unicode block [*Superscripts and Subscripts*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/superscripts_and_subscripts/list.htm) (for fairly obvious reasons). There doesn't seem to be a superscript number sign in Unicode at all, so you can't use this method here. [SW4's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19956460/73070) should work for arbitrary content.

Comment: @Joey -- Yeah, OSx char viewer is "unique"... lots of emojis and little buildings and flags and "thumbs up!", but no unicode.  Appreciated but [SW4's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19956460/4206306) won't work for me as I'm trying to do `:after {content: "#1";}` and Im already using the before for the trophy icon which is the backdrop for the `#1`.

Answer (score 4):

There is another solution, as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JBfz/)

```
element:before{
    content:'6'; 
    vertical-align: super; /* make superscript */
    font-size:8px;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `super` and `top`?

Comment: According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align): super:
Aligns the baseline of the element with the superscript-baseline of its parent. top: Align the top of the element and its descendants with the top of the entire line. Super is specifically for superscript.

Comment: `font-size: 1ex` is probably a better choice than a pixel size.

Comment: @Gray: have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/jZNRP/

Comment: @ExtPro Thanks a lot for that. I didn't really understand that distinction at first. The visual was extremely helpful.

Comment: @Gray: No worries, that's what SO is for :)

Comment: Just a minor update to @ExtPro 's JSFiddle to illustrate the difference in a clearer manner (basically I've just bumped the font sizes up, but hey) ;) http://jsfiddle.net/jZNRP/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
element:before {
    content: "6";
    font-size: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```