# How do I add additional info next to the product price in magento?

Tags: magento

Im trying to add pm2 (per meter squared) next to the price on the product page in magento, here is an example:

[image]

after looking at the souce code for how they showed this it was:

```
<span class="metres">m<sup>2</sup>
```

so I added that little bit of code to my theme template in magento file location (app/design/frontend/default/THEMENAME/template/catalog/product/view/price.phtml):

```
<div class="price-box" id="product_price">
<p class="old-price"><?php echo $this->__('Old Price:') ?><?php echo $this->getPrice() ?></p>
<p class="special-price"><?php echo $this->getPrice() ?><span class="metres">m<sup>2</sup></p>
</div>
```

but nothing shows up, see example:

[image]

any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Comment: What product type is the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative approach you could try the :afer pseudo element (see http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/). I don't like modifying core files (even if you do take a copy in your theme like you have) because a future upgrade may change the file significantly and your version might even become incompatible. This approach at least would avoid that.

And to get your superscripted 2, see [CSS :before superscript "6"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956362/css-before-superscript-6).

Answer (score 0):

if you look at price.phtml you will see there are many repetitions of price and special price, as the file is used to cover every possible price permutation - product type and tax display etc.  Step through each price echo and add [WHAT EVER] to the output until you find the code being fired for your particular instance and then add the m2 code to it.

EDIT: Looks like you are editing the wrong file.  You should edit template/catalog/product/price.html, not template/catalog/product/view/price.phtml.  You can see from your screen grab and your code they are not the same.  Your code is echo'ing 'old price' which doesnt appear.

Comment: I did price.phtml only has the code i have shown in the question Ive added the <span> code to it but nothing happens.

Comment: That edits the default magento theme and doesn't show using my current theme :(

Comment: I've just realised you are editing the wrong file, you should edit template/catalog/product/price.phtml, not template/catalog/product/view/price.phtml

Comment: and FYI - anything not being loaded from your own theme diretory will fall back to the base/default template.